# Converting PyCapsule to ctypes.c_void_p

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I have a python method in one library that returns a image handle as a PyCapsule. I need to pass the handle to another library that expects it as a c_void_p. How can I convert the capsule into a c_void_p to facilitate this interop?

I tried the following casts in Python, but to no avail

```
addr = ctypes.py_object(capsule)
```

Comment: Accessing [`PyCapsule_GetPointer`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/capsule.html#c.PyCapsule_GetPointer) through [`ctypes.pythonapi`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) would probably do it, but remember to set `argtypes` and `restype` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you. The following implementation worked.

```
ctypes.pythonapi.PyCapsule_GetName.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
ctypes.pythonapi.PyCapsule_GetName.argtypes = [ctypes.py_object]
name = ctypes.pythonapi.PyCapsule_GetName(capsule)

ctypes.pythonapi.PyCapsule_GetPointer.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
ctypes.pythonapi.PyCapsule_GetPointer.argtypes = [ctypes.py_object, ctypes.c_char_p]
addr = ctypes.pythonapi.PyCapsule_GetPointer(capsule, name)

addr = ctypes.c_void_p(addr)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).